# Which is correct: To "take a medical leave" or to "take medical leave"?

Tags: grammaticality, indefinite-articles

According to the *Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary* and *Cambridge Dictionaries Online*, *leave* is an uncountable noun when it is used to mean "a period of time away from work for a holiday/vacation or for a special reason." Thus, one should say or write,

> He's taken sick leave since last week.

However, I found the following sentences both added an 'a' before *leave*. Are both "without a" and "with a" in front of *leave* acceptable, even though the dictionaries I've consulted with don't show that *leave* is singular?

> At my request, the board of directors has granted me **a medical leave** of absence 
>     so I can focus on my health. (from [Job's letter to Apple Staff as he takes new 
>     medical leave of absence](http://www.hypebot.com/hypebot/2011/01/full-text-of-steve-jobs-letter-to-apple-staff-as-a-takes-new-medical-leave-of-absence.html))
>
> Steve Jobs' decision to **take a medical leave** from Apple Inc. was probably 
>     triggered either by an infection, a rejection episode related to his recent 
>     liver transplant or, most likely, a recurrence of his pancreatic cancer, 
>     experts said Monday. (from [*The Los Angeles Times*](http://articles.latimes.com/2011/jan/17/health/la-he-steve-jobs-medical-%20%20%2020110118))
>   P.S. One can find the usage, "to take a week's/a month's leave", in dictionaries. But, I don't think it is relevant to my question. It seems just another usage.

Answer (score 2):

When used as part of the phrase [leave of absence](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leave_of_absence), it's common to use an 'a' before leave.  It can also be pluralized to *leaves of absence* if need be.  E.g.

> Did you hear Bob had to take a medical leave of absence?
>
> Mary is out again.  That makes five leaves of absence in as many years.

Answer (score 2):

Both constructions are correct. The different usages arise from *leave*'s status as both a noun, and a portion of the mostly archaic verb phrase *to take leave*.

When it's used in the phrase, *take a medical leave*, *leave* is acting as a noun, and it's entirely akin to the word *vacation* or *break*.  *Medical* acts an adjective describing the noun.  As a noun, *leave* usually takes the preposition *on*, when it's used as an indirect object.

When it's used in the phrase, *take medical leave*, *take leave* is acting as a verb phrase, meaning "to depart," and *medical* is an adverb describing **how** the *leave* was taken.

Here are some usages of *leave* as a noun:

> I've been on **leave** for 6 months; no one has noticed and phoned me to return just yet!
>
> How long can the soldiers stay on **leave**?  The Germans have just crossed the Maginot Line.
>
> I gave PFC Downey and Lance Corporal Dawson **leave** to do as they liked; I certainly didn't order the Code Red.

Here are some usages of *to take leave* as an archaic verb:

> I **took leave** of my guests after making the requisite excuses, and prepared my pistols in the drawing room.
>
> When shall we **take leave** of dreary England and embark to the warm beaches of the Azores?
>
> I have **taken leave** of my employment with Mr. Holmes and wish to pursue the happiest of marriages with you, my dear Ms. Morstan.

Comment: Shouldn't `medical` change into `medically` when used as an adverb? Cf: "set him **completely** free". When an adjective is used, doesn't it require "a"? For example: `take part` -> `take an important part`.

Comment: @Ilya: yes, I think Billare is wrong about "take medical leave", which I don't think is a version of "take leave", but parses as "take [medical leave]". I also find "take a medical leave" odd, and would have assumed that it was an error (but not "take a medical leave of absence", which is fine, as Dusty says). Otherwise a good answer.